# How can I count only checked checkboxes in a PDF form?

Tags: javascript, pdf, checkbox, acrobat

There are a few check boxes in an Adobe PDF I have open in Acrobat. I want to count the checkboxes that have been checked and output the number in another textbox. How can I do that with JavaScript? Or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to set up a counter, enumerate all fields, check whether the field is a checkbox, and then whether its value is not "Off"; in that case increment the counter. A function doing that would look like this:

```js
function countCheckedBoxes() {
    var cntr = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
        var mf = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));
        if (mf.type == "checkbox") {
            if (mf.value != "Off") {
                cntr++;
            }
        }
    }
if (cntr > 0) {
    app.alert("The form has " + cntr + " checked boxes")
} else {
    app.alert("The form has no checked boxes") 
    }
}
```

and that should do it.

As the number of checked boxes should go into another field, you would replace the evaluation of `cntr` with the following code:

```
if (cntr > 0) {
    this.getField("boxCount").value = cntr + " boxes checked";
} else {
    this.getField("boxCount").value = "no boxes checked";
}
```

...or simply enter the value of `cntr`.

Answer (score 0):

I just was able to achieve this with a very simple script thanks to [a script by George Johnson back in 2008](https://acrobatusers.com/forum/forms-acrobat/calculating-checked-checkboxes/index.php#comment-49450).

What I did was create a text field, set it to read-only, and set it to be a custom computed value and put this in the script field:

```js
// Initialize counter variable
var sum = 0; 
// Loop through the fields
for (var i = 1; i < 180; i += 1) {
// Add one if check box is not Off
    if (getField("CheckBox" + i).value !== "Off") {sum += 1;}
} 
// Set this field's value to the sum
event.value = sum;
```

Important note: I have `"CheckBox" + i` and `i < 180` in my `for` loop because all my checkboxes are named "CheckBox1", "CheckBox2", etc. through "Checkbox180".

If your checkboxes all have unique names, you'll need to put those names in an array and loop through it in your code. And if you only have, say, 15 checkboxes, then change the 180 in the script to 15.